# How did iTunes install itself?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, itunes

So the other day, I was busy doing my thing, notably installing Visual Studio, when a command prompt popped up. I only had time to see the word "iTunes" before it closed. A moment later the user agreement came up and I saw that an iTunes icon found its way on my desktop.

I don't have any music on this computer, and it was imaged to Windows 8.1 just a few hours beforehand. I had NOT downloaded iTunes, nor any other Apple products, nor anything that might possibly be dependent on it (All that's here is Visual Studio, Google Chrome, and Office really). Not only that, but Visual Studio was installing at the same time, and I know that Windows doesn't allow multiple simultaneous installations! (In retrospect, it might have been updating post-installation, so that might not have counted...)

I am trying to figure out how iTunes got on my machine (don't tell me to uninstall, that's obvious, I want to know how it got there in there in the first place). It could be malware I suppose, but I hadn't gone to any site that could have done so (Basically just Microsoft and Google).

I opened the program and looked around to see if anything was off and, while I'm no security expert, if this is a spoof of iTunes, then it's the best damn spoof I've ever seen. The only thing that seems off is the fact that it's out of date (11.1.5.5, still with the blue icon (ah, the good old days...)), though it immediately asked to update when I first opened it.

I greped through some of the code, and I even see references to www.apple.com in DTD links, no typos. The only thing I've noticed that seems off would be the fact that there's no "iTunes Helper.exe" in startup programs (it always bothered me, and I made a point of removing it after each update). Perhaps this version is old for that, but it's just something I noticed. I've uploaded a few screenshots (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN8kL.jpg), maybe someone will notice something weird and be able to tell if it's a spoof.

Does anyone know of anyway to track how this ended up on my system? Perhaps a URL it downloaded from, or the location of the installer file? If it is legitimate then I want to know how Apple got the right to install this on my computer without my permission. And if it's a spoof, then it's one Apple needs to do something about, because it's pretty good one.

Comment: Check the digital sig on the main exe to make sure its legit. I think those 2 helper progs run by the registry or task scheduler now, not by start menu.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. The .exe is signed by Apple, issued by VeriSign. I don't see anything suspicious about it, so I can only guess it is legit. Question is then, how it got the rights to install on my machine.

Comment: on machines i have seen, the itunes installer required elevation through a UAC prompt. do you have UAC disabled?

Comment: UAC is disabled. I don't explicitly remember doing that since the imaging, but it is something I generally do when it starts to annoy me, so I wouldn't be surprised if I disabled it.

Comment: is it possible the visual studio installer checked an "optional" program that required itunes, and it just installed it? I say this because you got a type of unattended itunes install

Comment: There is something called Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova that may do this, but i have no way to confirm

Comment: I have (attempted) to install the Apache Cordova tools with Visual Studio (It tells me everything else failed, so I don't know how these programs succeeded), so that would make sense for Node and Git I suppose. Why would that require iTunes though? I can't say I've heard of a Microsoft product that linked to an Apple download.

Comment: My answer covers the details, but i am adding more information now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova is a set of tools to build cross platform apps. Visual Studio contains a secondary installer which gives you the option to install 3rd party software required for development, which includes iTunes for iOS deployment.

If the option for cross platform mobile development was checked for HTML/Javascript (Apache Cordova) it will prompt you to install the tools, with iTunes preselected, as well as Node.js, GIT CLI, Chrome, Apache Ant, JDK 7, and the Android SDK.

The [landing page for Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs.aspx) does NOT show iTunes in its list of tools, however the [installation notes page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx) does list it.

If you just clicked install on that prompt, it would have installed all of them using an unattended installation switch, which removes the main installer UIs for these programs.

Comment: I should note that this is only automatic for VS 2015, earlier versions required a separate download to get Cordova

Comment: This is probably the reason then. I suppose that makes sense, I just never expected a Microsoft product to automatically download an Apple program. Who knew?

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons:

- Is a system in a corporate Active Directory network?  The software may have been pushed to you for some reason.  We install ITunes on a few company computers here due to needing to support iPads.
- If iTunes had been on your system previously, but was deleted manually instead of through the Programs and Features menu, some install event may have triggered a repair operation, which I believe could, in the worst case, do a reinstall.  You may want to check Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer and look at the Windows -> System Logs around the time before the install happened.
- Do you have any Apple software on your system, such as iCloud or Quicktime?  You may have inadvertently left the iTunes box checked, or accidentally checked it, during the updater.
- Look in Programs and Features and check the install date, and use that to find clues of what may have happened.  Correlate with Event Viewer above.
- Does anyone else know your username and password?  Could someone have discovered your username and password?  Do a Winkey + R -> `sysdm.cpl`, then press Enter, then go to Advanced, then User Profiles.  This will show all profiles on your system, which would likely be anyone who's logged on to your system.  If you think your password is compromised, change it.

Comment: 1) It is a corporate system, but I spoke to IT and they claim they do not install it.
2) iTunes was never on this computer, and it was just reimaged. I'll check event viewer and system logs.
3) No Apple software should be present, I don't have iCloud or Quicktime or anything else. We're a Windows company too, IT would never install Apple software (said so themselves).
4) I'll check programs and features.
5) Under sysdm.cpl there's just me, the admin account, and "Default Profile". This happened WHILE I was using the computer, so it had to be done remotely at the very least.

Comment: Control Panel gives a source location under my AppData folder (C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Local\Temp\mddget\Downloads\iTunes64Setup\). Googling "mddget" returns nothing useful. The iTunes folder is gone now, but mddget has a "DependencyChecks.xml" file which references a number of missing programs, including Node, Git, Visual Studio, a number of Android packages, and (notably) iTunes. I believe these were all installed before the imaging, but I have not reinstalled them since. Despite this, Node, Git, and other programs have been installed without my knowledge. Any ideas where these came from?

Comment: Most likely it's a result of something done by your IT people (maybe they don't even realize it). As such, it's something they need to look into, and not really a question well-suited for this forum.